# Error when calling DevDemon Forms field

Tags: devdemon-forms

I am developing a directory and have created a channel that holds information such as name and logo etc for a business. In this channel I have used channel forms, although I have no idea how to actually integrate it into my html. Below I have shown some screen shots that show my code and the results im getting. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an outdated version of the [DevDemon Forms](http://www.devdemon.com/forms/) add-on which doesn't support the version of EE you're running - upgrade to the most current version (3.4.6).

(The error is that the `ip_address` column was removed from the `exp_security_hashes` table a few versions back.)